Google Drive API 400 Redirect_uri_mismatch
So i've just setup an app for the first time on GoogleDrive with the hope of using it as a back end for file storage for an application i'm developing.  I just wanted to get some of the Google Drive basis out of the way, like listing files, uploading and renaming but I cannot even get past the Auth.
I have setup a most basic Blazor Server app with the below code. It causes a browser to open with the below error.



@code {

    string[] Scopes = { DriveService.Scope.DriveReadonly };
    string ApplicationName = "Drive API .NET Quickstart";

    UserCredential credential;

    protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        // credentials.json points to the file containing the client ID and client secret.
        var clientSecrets = await GoogleClientSecrets.FromFileAsync("client_secret.json");

        credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            clientSecrets.Secrets,
            new[] { DriveService.ScopeConstants.DriveFile },
            "user",
            CancellationToken.None);

        var driveService = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential
            });
    }
}

I have however, set the redirect uri in the google console, I also made sure to download the new Secret.json file. However, I also noticed that the port listed in the attached screenshot changes every single time I run the app so no matter what I would do, this error will always come back?
I understand that there are many similar posts but I've never seen one mention that the port is always being rotated?
Is there a better way to do this in 2024?

there is local and remote port number.  The remote port number is always the same.  The local port number can change and is not your issue.  The error is due to flowname=GeneralOAuthFlow.  There are two types of Credentials 1) Windows 2) OAUTH2,  You are trying to use OAUTH2 when the server only wants Windows Credentials.

I appreciate the answer, though i'm not certain where I should be looking instead?

Your app needs to be running HTTPS

I was finally able to list my files using this - link

I was able to connect using a service account and list my files using this link Google Drive API V3 Service Account
